# MediaWiki JSON API - Get all the date in List of wiki page

Tags: json, rest, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I need help on the MediaWiki API where I want just all the data of each president (image url, name and url, state, term, etc...) in a json format: [List of Presidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States#List_of_presidents).

I am already following the [help page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&recursivesubmodules=1#query) for query and it's not helpful in targeting just the table list. Is there a way to do this where it's not in a lump sum of html? Thanks

Comment: Try adding &format=json to your query. If that doesn't work, we'll need to see your query code...

Comment: Oh alright. I guess I have to parse the html myself. Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: If you are not married to the idea of that particular list you could try querying wikidata instead. That gives you structured data (so you don't need to parse wikitext) but you would have to write some sparql or at least modify one of the examples at https://query.wikidata.org

Comment: @Lokal_Profil that looks promising but does the rest endpoint option work in ajax? When I select that, it downloaded a sparql file.

Comment: It should. I use it to get json. Although I actually rnd up using the `https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql?format=json&query=` endpoint